# Can Postgres be used to take only the portion of a date from a field?

Tags: python, postgresql

Say you have a column that contains the values for the year, month and date. Is it possible to get just the year? In particular I have

`ALTER TABLE pmk_pp_disturbances.disturbances_natural ADD COLUMN sdate timestamp without time zone;`

and want just the `2004` from `2004-08-10 05:00:00`. Can this be done with Postgres or must a script parse the string? By the way, any rules as to when to "let the database do the work" vs. let the script running on the local computer do the work? I once heard querying databases is slower than the rest of the program written in C/C++, generally speaking.

Comment: `extract` operator might be what you are looking for: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-datetime.html

Comment: There are no rules for database vs script and speed is usually not the criterion on which to decide. Databases let you perform very complex data analysis and they are secure and allow concurrent access, if properly set up. Try that with a python script... So it all depends on what you need; for a single-user stand-alone app, don't go with a database, for anything that goes beyond that have a good look.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`extract`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT):

```
SELECT extract('year' FROM sdate) FROM pmk_pp_disturbances.disturbances_natural;
```

For many queries it's worth investigating whether the database can perform the data transformations as needed. That being said, it also depends on what your application will do with the data so it's a trade-off as to whether the work should be done by the database or in the application.

Comment: Why did you change from using `date_trunk()`? It worked in my program.

Comment: Based on the documentation, date_trunc actually truncates to a specified precision. So in general, that's not what you asked - you want a part of the data unchanged (which is what extract does), you don't want data to be truncated / altered by Postgres.

Comment: Why on Earth does `extract 'year'` return a float and not an integer?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT date_part('year', your_column) FROM your_table;
```

Answer (score -3):

I think no. You're forced to read the entire value of a column. You can divide the date in few columns, one for the year, another for the month, etc. , or store the date on an integer format if you want an aggressive space optimization. But it will doing the database worst about scalability and modifications.

The databases are slow, you must assume it, but they offer hardest things to do with C/C++.

If you think make a game and save your 'save game' on SQL forget it. Use it if you're doing a back-end server or a management application, tool, etc.

Comment: Don't answer questions if you only "think so". I know for a fact that there is a very straightforward solution and very much better than storing individual date parts as integers. Databases are also not "slow" by definition, it all depends on your data and how that and the server are organized.

Comment: Especially when a quick Google search before answering would show that it's easy to do. Advising to divide the date into columns is *awful* advice, btw, the exact opposite of what you should do for efficiency and easy querying. Also, seriously "*The databases are slow*". Most of the time "I can do that better in the client" means they don't know how to use the server properly, and I get paid to come in and clean up the resulting train-wreck monstrosity later. Trying to build a game mainly in the DB isn't a great idea though, I agree.